# Getting button input from module on tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-module, tkinter-button

I am working on a project that uses buttons, but I would like to make it modular. The only problem I can't seem to get pass by is getting if someone is pressing the button from a different file

-file 1

```
from tkinter import*
class app2:
    def __init__(self):
        s = Tk()

        but = Button(text="Test",command=subcommand)
        but.pack()
        s.mainloop()


def subcommand():
    x = command()
    x.command



class command:
    def __init__(self,int):
        self.command = ()










y = app2()
```

file 2-

```
from tkinter import*
from idea2 import *


def clicked():
    print("HI")



x = command()
x.command(clicked())
```

My code basically just takes a function from another file and loads it into the command class. So basically the button can get different commands from different files. I don't know what to put for "x = command(???)" because I am trying to get that from a different file.

Basic question:
How to make my Tkinter button modular.

SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass the callback into the app2 constructor

#### file1

```
from tkinter import*
class app2:
    def __init__(self,btn_callback=subcommand):
        s = Tk()

        but = Button(text="Test",command=btn_callback)
        but.pack()
        s.mainloop()
```

#### file2

```
from idea import app2
def my_callback(*args,**kwargs):
    print("Buttton pressed...")
app = app2(my_callback)
```

or better yet make use of the event system in tkinter ... something like this

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox


def helloCallBack(*a,**kw):
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

class MyApp(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = Tkinter.Button(self, text ="Hello", command = lambda:self.event_generate("<<button_click>>"))
        self.b.pack()

app = MyApp()
app.bind("<<button_click>>",helloCallBack)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just relised I could have done that. Thanks a lot!